# In Visual Studio, is it possible to add an add-in assembly as a reference to another assembly in the solution?

Tags: c#, excel, add-in

I am using Visual Studio 2010.  I have multiple C# projects in my solution.  One of the projects is an Excel Add-In.  I want to be able to write unit tests on some of the code that I have in the Excel Add-In project.  To do this, I have created another project in the solution.  I want this test project to be able to reference the Add-In project. However, the Add-In project does not show up on the Projects tab of the Add Reference dialog.  The only way that I have been able to do anything is by adding the Add-In dll file as a reference in the test project.  This is not ideal, because a new dll would have to be generated whenever changes are made in the Add-In project.  Is this a limitation of Excel Add-In projects?  Or do I need to set the Excel Add-In project up in a particular way to make it visible to the test project?

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you just create the test classes under a different namespace in the excel addin?

```
ExcelAddin.Tests
```

If you are not familiar with namespaces then take a look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z2kcy19k(VS.80).aspx

Comment: Creating a different namespace in the Excel add-in is certainly an option, but I'd rather keep the tests in a completely separate project.  What I did was I installed the ProPowerTools add-in in Visual Studio, and it was able to find the Excel add-in project and successfully add it to the assembly.

Comment: Ben, you shouldn't have needed that. I don't know why you were having the troubles that you were having. An Excel add-in is just a standard project like any other. Glad you are on your feet though. :-)